# python scipy.optimize broken after upgrade

Tags: python, scipy

I was previously using `scipy version 0.14` and it worked fine for me. But today, I needed the parameter "bounds" in the `scipy.optimize` function curve_fit which apparently is only available in version 0.17 or higher. I therefore upgraded my `scipy` by typing

```
sudo pip install scipy==0.19
```

into my terminal. The upgrade worked, but now I cannot import `scipy.optimize` anymore.

I get the error message:

> ImportError: cannot import name minpack2

I tried downgrading to `scipy 0.17` and also back to `0.14` but I still get the same error message. Does anybody know what is going on?

Edit: The problem seems to have resolved itself. I closed and restarted Idle and can now import scipy.optimize without problems again.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Max OS X 10.6.8